# Invoking methods through java jmx functionality where the parameter is an ArrayList

Tags: java, connection, parameter-passing, jmx

I know that is possible to invoke a method in a java class using jmx like this:

```
try {   JMXServiceURL serviceUrl = new JMXServiceURL(URL);
        jmxConnector = JMXConnectorFactory.connect(serviceUrl, null);           
        ObjectName objectName = new ObjectName("whatever");
        MBeanServerConnection mbeanConn = jmxConnector.getMBeanServerConnection();      
        ret = (String)mbeanConn.invoke(objectName, methodName, paramsForInvoke, signitureForInvoke);
    }
```

In case we want to invoke the method with parameters, we need to pass the actual parameters as a Object array and the type of the parameters as a String array.
So let's continue the example above, let say if I want to pass a String ArrayList called sList:

```
ArrayList<String> sList = new ArrayList<String>();
sList.add("kapd_be");
Object  paramsForInvoke[] = {sList};
String  signitureForInvoke[] = {ArrayList.class.getName()};
```

In this case everything works fine, the method gets invoked with the appropriate parameter.
And I am able to extract The "kapd_be" String in the invoked method.

But if I want the parameter to be an ArrayList of some other class let say SortInfo, (which is a POJO class written by me and contains several fields) the code does not execute, I can't  even invoke the method, so obviously no parameters can be extracted.
This is strange because the only difference is this:

```
 ArrayList<SortInfo> sList = new ArrayList<SortInfo>();
```

Why? And how to pass a a SortInfo list to the method?

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/management/MBeanServerConnection.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Generics will be type erased at runtime, so consider your operation parameter as a list of Objects. This means that if you have multiple operations with the same name and the  same number of parameters, you will need to modify something. (i.e. the generic type of the List cannot be the only differentiation). So the lists can be typed at compile time, but at runtime, what you defined as a list of SortInfos, is actually a list of Objects and if you pass in a list containing objects that are not SortInfos, well.... G.I.G.O.

I also recommend you simply use a `List<[Type]>` as your parameter. And as **pr123** noted, the values in the list that you pass as arguments do need to be serializable, but only if your invocation will be serialized in order to reach the target MBeanServer. (In the example below, it will not).

Here's an example:

**Interface**

```
public interface GenericOpServiceMBean {
    public String op(List<Date> dates);
}
```

**Impl**

```
public class GenericOpService implements GenericOpServiceMBean {
    public String op(List<Date> dates) {
        if(dates==null || dates.isEmpty()) return "";
        StringBuilder b = new StringBuilder();
        for(Date d: dates) {
            b.append("\n\t").append(d);
        }
        return b.toString();
    }
}
```

**Test**

```
public class GenericArgsMBeanTest {

    public static final MBeanServer SERVER = ManagementFactory.getPlatformMBeanServer();

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        log("GenericArgsMBeanTest");
        try {
            ObjectName on = new ObjectName("test:svc=Generic");
            SERVER.registerMBean(new GenericOpService(), on);
            // invoking public String op(List<Date> dates);
            List<Date> dates = new ArrayList<Date>(Arrays.asList(new Date[]{
                    new Date(System.currentTimeMillis()),
                    new Date(System.currentTimeMillis()-1000),
                    new Date(System.currentTimeMillis()-10000)
            }));
            String result = (String)SERVER.invoke(on, "op", new Object[]{dates}, new String[]{List.class.getName()});
            // Note: We need to use the List class name, not ArrayList.
            log("Result:\n" + result);
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace(System.err);
        }
    }


    public static void log(Object msg) {
        System.out.println(msg);
    }
}
```

**Output**

```
GenericArgsMBeanTest
Result:

    Tue Jun 25 10:44:15 EDT 2013
    Tue Jun 25 10:44:14 EDT 2013
    Tue Jun 25 10:44:05 EDT 2013
```

Comment: actually implementing the seriazable interface solved my problem, but I accepted your answer for the detailed explanation

Comment: It escaped my notice that you answered your own question... :)

Answer (score 0):

SortInfo class must implement Serializable